# onDraw calling frequently

Tags: android

i have a method which displays a map. i call this method in onDraw method. but on Action move i need to redraw the map and need to call that method again but i am not getting canvas reference to redraw the map tiles. i used invalidate method but it start refreshing the onDraw frequently which made my map movement too to slow..

here is my onDraw method.

```
protected void onDraw(Canvas canvas)
        {   
            Log.i("On Draw Call", "On Draw call");
            mapMaker.getMapForScreenArea(map.getiScrnArea(), mapType, input, canvas);

            invalidate();
            this.canvas = canvas;
        }
```

any help will be appreciative.
thanks a lot.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`onDraw()` gets called again and again because you `invalidate()` every time.
And also `this.canvas = canvas` is unnecessary.